# path connected componenet and connected components in a Lie group coincide

Tags: lie-groups, connectedness

does anyone have an explanation\proof as to why path connected components and connected components of Lie groups coincide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lie group is a manifold, and this is true for every manifold.

Comment: But may be wrong if the Lie group is infinite dimensional?